# \[Errno -101\] NetCDF: HDF error when opening netcdf file

Tags: hdf5, netcdf, h5py, netcdf4

I have this error when opening my netcdf file.
The code was working before.
**How do I fix this ?**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       ...
>
> File "file.py", line 71, in gather_vgt
>       return xr.open_dataset(filename)
>
> File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line
>   286, in open_dataset
>       autoclose=autoclose)
>
> File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py",
>   line 275, in open
>       ds = opener()
>
> File "/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py",
>   line 199, in _open_netcdf4_group
>       ds = nc4.Dataset(filename, mode=mode, **kwargs)
>
> File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2015, in
>   netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.**init**
>
> File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1636, in
>   netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
>
> OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'file.nc'

When I try to open the same netcdf file with h5py I get this error :

> OSError: Unable to open file (file locking disabled on this file
>   system (use HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING environment variable to override),
>   errno = 38, error message = '...')

Answer (score 17):

You must be in this situation :

- your HDF5 library has been updated (1.10.1) (netcdf uses HDF5 under the hood)
- your file system does not support the file locking that the HDF5 library uses.

In order to read your hdf5 or netcdf files, you need set this [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) :

```
 HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE
```

---

For references, this was introduced in [HDF5 version 1.10.1](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.1/src/hdf5-1.10.1-RELEASE.txt),

> Added a mechanism for disabling the SWMR file locking scheme.
>
> The file locking calls used in HDF5 1.10.0 (including patch1)
>    will fail when the underlying file system does not support file
>    locking or where locks have been disabled. To disable all file
>     locking operations, an environment variable named
>         HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING can be set to the five-character string
>         'FALSE'. This does not fundamentally change HDF5 library
>   operation (aside from initial file open/create, SWMR is lock-free),
>   but users will have to be more careful about opening files
>   to avoid problematic access patterns (i.e.: multiple writers)                                                                                                                    >that the file locking was designed to prevent.
>
> Additionally, the error message that is emitted when file lock
>         operations set errno to ENOSYS (typical when file locking has been
>         disabled) has been updated to describe the problem and potential
>         resolution better.
>
> (DER, 2016/10/26, HDFFV-9918)

Comment: Thank you so much! save my life. 
In my case, I need to 
 export HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE

because I open the netcdf file in Jupyter notebook. need to export to the environment before I use the Jupyter notebook. 
I also added this command into the .bashrc, so it will automatically execute it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the solution as suggested by @Florian did not work. I found another solution, which suggested that the order in which `h5py` and `netCDF4` are imported matters (see [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/44668444-oserror-netcdf-hdf-error-if-netcdf4-and-h5py-installed-together)).

And, indeed, the following works for me:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import h5py
```

Switching the order results in the error as described by OP.