# NetCDF file reading in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray

I have converted several raster files into NetCDF file using ArcMap10.5. Now I want to open  netcdf file in python 3.6.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4
import xarray as xr
import h5py
import glob

allfiles = glob.glob('\folder*.nc')
for file in allfiles:
    file = xr.open_dataset(file).to_dataframe()
    list_of_dfs.append(file)
    print(file)
```

Getting following error:

```
SError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error:'file.nc'
```

I tried Setting environmental variable HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317927/errno-101-netcdf-hdf-error-when-opening-netcdf-file)
But, still getting that error. Is there anyone who can help? Thanks

Comment: Is there a file called 'file.nc' in the source directory? Also, you might want to check if the produced netCDF files are valid. For instance, check the input file with `ncdump -h 'file.nc'` from terminal.

Comment: It was a simple mistake, after changing environmental variable HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE I needed to restart jupyter notebook, so it worked then.