# Can't open in edit mode a netCDF file in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4, oserror

I'm trying to open a netCDF file in edit mode in Python using the netCDF4 library. The error I'm getting is this:
`OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'example.nc'`
OS: Ubuntu 22:04
IDE: VS Code
It's also worth noticing that I'm using the Jupyter in vs code.
My Code:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import h5py
import os
os.getcwd()
file = 'example.nc'
dataset = nc.Dataset(file, 'r+')
```

Full error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 6
      4 os.getcwd()
      5 file = 'example.nc'
----> 6 dataset = nc.Dataset(file, 'r+') # Open the netCDF file in read mode
      7 print(dataset)

File src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx:2463, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__()

File src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx:2026, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()

OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'example.nc'
```

I already gave checked if the file has write-to-read permissions and it has. So that's not problem probaly.
[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaGO0.png)

Comment: Have you looked at this question asking the same thing? It's likely your problem is the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317927/errno-101-netcdf-hdf-error-when-opening-netcdf-file

Comment: Yes I already saw that question unfortunately it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Without access to the file that is causing you problems ('example.nc'), it will be very hard to say what the actual problem is. Can you share it somewhere, or share a smaller file that has the same issue?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VDS-r-E7WTU1Ed6IdTaUMjGTua5UG_vQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The error `OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error` may occurs if you try to open a file for reading and writing (with `r+`), but you are only allowed to read that file.

To fix this:

- If you only need to read the file, then use `r` instead of `r+`.
- If you need to edit the file in place, change the permissions (on linux with something like `chmod 755 myfile.nc`) before opening it with `r+`.
- If you can't change the permission, you may want to try xarray instead of netcdf4-python.